# How do you query opensearch data with the javascript opensearch client library?

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-opensearch

I am trying to figure out how to do a simple match_all query of aws opensearch using the

@aws-sdk/client-opensearch library

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-opensearch/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-opensearch/classes/opensearch.html

Would anyone have an example of this? Cannot find any good examples online.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@opensearch-project/opensearch](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-js) client for that purposes.

Then you can perform search queries like:

```js
var query = {
  query: {
    match: {
      title: {
        query: 'The Outsider',
      },
    },
  },
};

var response = await client.search({
  index: index_name,
  body: query,
});

console.log(response.body.hits);
```

Check [their user guide](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-js/blob/main/USER_GUIDE.md#user-guide) for more snippets